# Dynamic field in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a cursor that iterates a table. Each row is inserted into a type that is equal to the cursor row.

```
 CURSOR lc_lines
    IS
          SELECT tlc1, tlc2, tlc3
            FROM table_x
        ORDER BY tlc1;

    TYPE table_lines IS TABLE OF lc_lines%ROWTYPE
                            INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    i_table_lines                 table_lines;
```

I needed to dynamically access the columns in the type. Something like this:

```
LOOP
            FETCH lc_lines
            BULK COLLECT INTO i_table_lines
            LIMIT p_i_limit;

            --e ai vamos nos :)
            FOR i_idx IN 1 .. i_table_lines.COUNT
            LOOP
                varx := i_table_lines (i_idx).tlc||'2';
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple answer **NO**. In Any (atleast most) high level language, variable name is not allowed to be dynamic. Only the memory allocation is.

Comment: Fala Andre (brazuca :-) - I do not get it - since you know your cursor fields beforehand (tlc1, tlc2, and tlc3 - which is all there is going to be available to you anyway in the loop - what dynamic data do you need/are you referring to ?

Comment: @ Maheswaran Ravisanka: I don't know in which context you are basing your answer. But I do not think it is right. In C#, a high level language (and  a sufficiently widespread and accepted one), you can work with variables of type "dynamic" (no compile /type checks whatsoever, like javascript). And let's not forget we are talking about PL/SQL here, a DB manipulation language, ultimately.

Comment: @Veverke Variable type may be global(like `id` in `Objective-C `that I know of). What I mean here is the variable name itself.

Comment: @Veverke ... well, i must think in another solution to the problem :( .Imagine for some reason you want to access field in the row based in a parameter in an application.

Comment: @Andre Fonseca: I know this is not ideal, but can't you set a convention to the parameter names allowed for the external applications (assuming they are under your control... which is probably not the case :/  )

Comment: @Veverke ... that is a possibility ... thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AndréFonseca: then you would define the table/cursor columns accordingly. Espero que seja aplicavel ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use DBMS_SQL routines to do this ... it's there to assist with complex, dynamic SQL/cursors, etc.

Try reading over the documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS00001

You basically setup your cursor, your binds, your columns, etc.
then you can start accessing them without necessarily knowing how many columns you have in the first place.

[edit] I linked to the oracle 11 page, however, that feature's pretty much same between Oracle 10 and 11 .. here's the 10g doc if you need :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i996963
[/edit]